# In S_3, an even permutation must have an odd number of orbits. True or False?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Well, somehow i considered the unit cycle of S_3 : (123). And since it can be expressed as a product of 2 transpositions mainly: (12)(13) which i believe proved S_3 to be an even permutation. I have a feeling that the statement is true...
However, i'm not too sure because can't seem to understand the second part of the statement: "...must have an odd number of orbits". 
Any help would do.

Comment: You're right about $(123)$. The orbit of an element is the orbit of the subgroup generated by that element. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, most beginning texts use left actions instead of right actions, in which case you have multiplied in the wrong order. I would write $(123)=(13)(12)$, and $(12)(12)=(132)$ because I apply the rightmost permutation first. You may wish to double-check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: There are only 6 elements in this group (how many will be even?). So you may as well just make a list.

For example, you have $(123)$. By applying this permutation (perhaps more than once), you can send any element of $\{1,2,3\}$ to any other. So the elements are all in the same orbit. Hence  this even permutation has an odd number (1) of orbits.

The identity leaves each element alone. So each element is its own orbit, and you have three orbits. Is the identity even or odd?

I leave the other elements for you. Feel free to comment if you get stuck.

Comment: thanks. somehow i've identified all the 6 elements of S_3, however i cannot follow the work which you have done to obtain the order you stated above. If you could further elaborate on that part again, i'm sure i'll fully understand.

Comment: @Sai82 Sorry, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Could you perhaps restate your question?

Comment: just to check if i'm on the right track. S_3 having 6 elements: (1) having 3 orbits. (23),(12) and (13) had 2 orbits each AND (123) and (132) had 1 orbit each. So, summarizing, even permutations has odd number of orbits whereas odd permutations has even number of orbits.

Comment: Looks right to me.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The orbit-stabilizer theorem could be of use.  Choose any even permutation $s \in S_3$.

$$|G_s||O_s| = |S_3| = 6$$

Where $G_s$ is the subgroup of elements that fix $s$ (the stabilizer) and $O_s$ is the set of elements in the orbit of $s$.  Now try to find the order of the stabilizer subgroup, noting that an even permutation composed with an even permutation is even, and an even permutation composed with an odd permutation is odd.